# Setting up environment variables in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, environment-variables

How can we set up the PATH environment variable in Visual Studio 2010 for the entire solution/project?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish??

Comment: My situation is so because I have dependency on dll's for reference dll, it would work only if I have those dll's in my output directory. I got that working in pre-build events, how ever after the build when I try to execute the application it fails. So I wanted to set up those dll's in path so that it can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to refer to a reference .dll, it has worked for me to set up a Solution Explorer level folder, and add the DLL file to that folder. Then in the filesystem, I add a matching folder (since the Solution folder is logical and not a real folder) at the solution level. There I put the physical DLL file, and if you are using source control, check-in that directory.

Once that's all done, for any project that needs to reference that DLL file, I can browse to it on the Solution level, add the reference, and make sure that the properties are set to 'Copy Local,' so that the DLL file shows in the appropriate `/bin` folder.

I would try something like that to get your dependencies better organized.